# Laravel authenticate just refreshes on login

Tags: laravel, authentication

Using Laravel 5.4 here.

I have setup Auth on existing (awful designed) Database and I want to run the authentication, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have set up my User model in \App as follows:

```
protected $table = 'user';
protected $fillable = [
   'username', 'password',
];
```

This is because the field with the email is called username in the database and the database itself is called user.

Also I have added

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

So the login tries to look for this. Every error that it was previously giving stopped showing, but now when I try to login (even with wrong credentials) it just refreshes the login page without any feedback or even an error.

It's my first time setting this up so .. is there something else I need to change in order to make it work with my existing table?

Comment: you are complaining about awful design and can't get to work a very basic thing. Actually you do not need to set up your User model it is already defined for you. And it is redirecting you because you are not being able to pass validation! Prolly u messed up something and u cant see the error messages so try to add on login blade   @if(errors->has()) and display them

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying, I wasn't complaining, just mentioning why this needs fiddling with. My field should be "username" as I changed it in the view and in the model and the table is called user. Thing is, it obviously checks but returns the "These credentials do not match our records." when they do for sure. I am sure it probably is a rookie mistake but I'm really setting this up for the first time and wasn't able to figure it out via Laravel docs.